# Math.random() *100 verses Math.random(100)

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I stumbled on the Math class. I was wondering if there was a difference between Math.random() *100 verses Math.random(100)? Would both outputs be a number between 0-99 or would Math.random(100) output a number between 0-100? 
Thank you!

Comment: There is no method in `Math` called `random` that takes any parameters; there is only the one that takes no parameters.

Comment: you should carefully take a look to the doc....

Comment: Definitely recommend trying to run code as a first step

Comment: What do the docs for `Math.random()` vs `Math.random(100)` say (hint one doesn't exist)? Do the docs say the random number max is inclusive (0-99) or exclusive (0-100)? If I remember correctly `Math.random()` returns a random float from 0 to 1. Does multiplying every possible float from 0 to 1 result in a number between 0 and 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#random()) exists.  `Math.random(int)` does *not* exist.

You may be getting that mixed up with the [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#%3Cinit%3E(long)) class constructor, which takes a `long` as a seed value, meaning your results will be pseudorandom and by consequence, repeatable.

If you wanted a number between 0 and 99 I actually would recommend that you use `Random`.  You can leverage `random.nextInt(100)` to get a value between 0 and 99.  [Multiplying floats gets dicey very quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1079354), since `Math.random()` only produces a floating-point number.